# Font Icon for StackOverflow logo?

Tags: css, fonts, icon-fonts

Looking for icon font for StackOverflow to use similar with techniques similar to [Fontello](http://fontello.com) or [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/).

[I see an open issue for it here.](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/251) Perhaps this is as close as it gets for now.

Cheers,
jf

Comment: Perhaps you should ask at [meta]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This icon set contains it and it is Bootstrap/Foundation compatible: 
http://aristeides.com/elusive-iconfont/

Cheers! :)

That link is dead - try http://elusiveicons.com/icons/

Comment: Thanks RynoRn! Also, just found that this icon is actually in Fontello's Elusive set.

Comment: Welcome! Yeah, It's a great font-icon.